# How to Select An Element By Id and Change The Value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a html element of the form
`<input type="hidden" id="someId" value="something">"`.
Which javascript command will overwrite value?

Thanks for the answer

Comment: Best before check the internet for this question.. i remove below vote!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('someId').value = 'somethingElse';
```

This is pretty basic, though... You could easily have found this elsewhere..